# SQL "SELECT" Command Not Working, even though entry is in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have created the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE QuizRepo (
User_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name TEXT
)
```

I populate it via JDBC, and when I populate it, I get:

```
mysql> select * from QuizRepo;
| User_ID | Name    |
|       1 | "XXQuiz"|
```

When I do the following command, it works as expected:

```
mysql> select * from QuizRepo where USER_ID=1;
User_ID | Name      |
|       1 | "XXQuiz"|
```

However, when I do the following command, I get a weird result

```
mysql> select * from QuizRepo where Name="XXQuiz";
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Has anyone seen this happen before? How could this be possible? Perhaps I am adding it in the DB incorrectly (doesnt seem likely) but then you can clearly see there is an entry called "XXQuiz" so why is it not finding it?

Comment: Mine is returning correct ... which version of mysq are you using?

Comment: Seems to work fine => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/630b5/1

Comment: Bear in mind that in SQL you should use single quotes for delimiting your strings. (MySQL will let you get away with double quotes [if ANSI_QUOTES isn't turned on](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html), but it's best practice to use single quotes.) I'm guessing a minor misunderstanding of how quoting is done might have led to you putting your `Name` in the database unexpectedly wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've stored the quotes as well.  So you'll need to so a : 
`select * from QuizRepo where Name = "\"XXQuiz\"";`

or similar.

Comment: Or just not store the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Could be you  name don't match exactly check for this and try also

```
select * from QuizRepo where Name like "%XXQuiz%";
```